# Cannot have inject dynamic instance in quarkus when using @Dependent

Tags: java, cdi, quarkus

I am using a library that is not thread safe and I want a fresh instance of that library object whenever I use it. I made a test repo here : https://github.com/lud/test-quarkus-arc

The library comes with two classes, `SomeLibraryClass`, which I need to use, and `SomeLibraryClassDependency` which is required by the former, and which is the thread-unsafe one.

I was trying to get all that working by using this factory-ish class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyAppFactory {
  @Dependent
  @Produces
  SomeLibraryClassDependency getDep() {
    return new SomeLibraryClassDependency();
  }

  @Dependent
  @Produces
  SomeLibraryClass getUsable(SomeLibraryClassDependency dep) {
    return new SomeLibraryClass(dep);
  }

  @Inject
  Instance<MyAppClass> myClass;

  public MyAppClass getNewMyClass() {
    return myClass.get();                // <-- this fails
  }
}
```

This is some test code I would like to compile. I am calling the factory getter twice, and I verify that my class uses a different instance of the `SomeLibraryClassDependency` class.

```
@Test
public void testHelloEndpoint() {
  var a = factory.getNewMyClass();
  var b = factory.getNewMyClass();
  assertNotEquals(a.getUsabeId(), b.getUsabeId());
}
```

Here is the class that should be instantiated by calling `Instance<MyAppClass>#get`:

```
@Dependent
public class MyAppClass {
  @Inject
  SomeLibraryClass usable;

  public MyAppClass() {

  }

  public Integer getUsabeId() {
    return usable.getId();
  }
}
```

Finally here is the code for the library mocks:

```
public class SomeLibraryClass {

  private SomeLibraryClassDependency dep;

  public SomeLibraryClass(SomeLibraryClassDependency dep) {
    this.dep = dep;
  }

  public Integer getId() {
    return dep.getId();
  }
}


public class SomeLibraryClassDependency {

  private static Integer n = 0;
  private Integer id;

  public SomeLibraryClassDependency() {
    n += 1;
    this.id = n;
  }

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }
}
```

When trying to compile that, I have the following error, and I do not understand why

> [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.quarkus.arc.runtime.BeanContainer$Instance<org.acme.getting.started.MyAppClass> and qualifiers [@Default]
>
> - java member: org.acme.getting.started.MyAppFactory#myClass
> - declared on CLASS bean [types=[org.acme.getting.started.MyAppFactory, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.acme.getting.started.MyAppFactory]

I was thinking that since `MyAppClass` has the `@Dependent` annotation, it should be resolved.

Edit: I know I can also define a producer for my class, but my end goal is to be able to @Inject other things in that class (like a logger) and let the container do its job.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for the exact same thing. One question, any reason why you're now using both annotations, `@Produces` and `@Dependent`?

Comment: @StefanoL I don't remember at all. Maybe I thought It was necessary because i dot not know what scope `@Produces` defines by default.

Comment: I see, because for me it works with `@Produces` only. I just had the wrong import which is a nice easy pitfall by Quarkus I guess, because `@Produces` is also used in `Controllers` but with a different import to state which content-type it produces :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says `Unsatisfied dependency for type io.quarkus.arc.runtime.BeanContainer$Instance<org.acme.getting.started.MyAppClass>`, which suggests that you have a wrong import for the `Instance` class. The correct one is `javax.enterprise.inject.Instance`.